# How come I can't successfully load an NSImage from it's full path? Swift 2

Tags: macos, nsdata, nsimage, swift-playground, swift2

I'm trying to load an image from an absolute path into an `NSImage` and even though the same full path works in other scenarios when I'm using it in this context, the variable just ends up being `nil`. I've tried using both the file path and an `NSURL` to achieve it.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa
import AppKit

print ("Starting")

/**
    Attempt to do via NSURL
**/

// The workspace
var workspace = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
// Main screen
var screen = NSScreen.mainScreen()

let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
print(filemgr.currentDirectoryPath)

let filePath1 = "/Users/daniel/Google Drive/elementarian wallpapers/Bicycle by midnighttokerkate.png"
let filePath2 = "/Users/daniel/Google Drive/elementarian wallpapers/Buildings Foggy Sky by solutionall.png"

let file1 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath1, isDirectory: false)
let file2 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath2, isDirectory: false)

do {
    try workspace.setDesktopImageURL(file2, forScreen: screen!, options: [:])
    print("Successfully set background from NSURL")
} catch {
    print("Failed to set")
}

print("Attempting to set from NSData...")

/**
    Attempt to do via NSData
**/

// Load image from URL first
if filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(filePath2) {
    print("File exists")

    var image = NSImage(contentsOfURL: file2)

    if image != nil {
        print ("Not nil")
    } else {
        print ("Nil")
    }
} else {
    print("File not found")
}
```

My final goal is to load the image into an `NSData` object so I can run a transform on it and then set the manipulated in memory image as the desktop background.

Comment: Is the app sandboxed?

Comment: It's entirely possible. This is the first I've heard of sandboxing so thanks for that. According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26980051/2977837) the Playgrounds are sandboxed so I'm going to try their suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Droppy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086999/how-come-i-cant-successfully-load-an-nsimage-from-its-full-path-swift-2?noredirect=1#comment50191215_31086999), this was due to the Swift Playground running in a sandbox and not allowing access to files outside of it's workplace. I've moved the images I need into the playground itself to test and it now works as expected. Details on how to do this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26980051/2977837).